# How to set up a cluster using Infinispan Server 10.0.0

Tags: cluster-computing, infinispan

I'm trying to cluster two Infinispan Server jvm's but I'm not having much luck finding a working example. I need to use TCPPING. Here's an example of what I added to the infinispan.xml file.

```
<infinispan
```

'''
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:10.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-10.0.xsd
                                urn:infinispan:server:10.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-server-10.0.xsd
                                urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups-4.0.xsd"
            xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:10.0"
            xmlns:server="urn:infinispan:server:10.0">

```
   <jgroups>
   <stack name="tcp">
        <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"/>
        <protocol type="TCPPING">
            <property name="initial_hosts">1.1.1.1[7800],2.2.2.2[7800]</property>
            <property name="num_initial_members">2</property>
            <property name="port_range">0</property>
            <property name="timeout">2000</property>
        </protocol>
        <protocol type="MERGE3"/>
        <protocol type="FD_SOCK"/>
        <protocol type="FD_ALL"/>
        <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
        <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2"/>
        <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
        <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
        <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
        <protocol type="MFC"/>
        <protocol type="FRAG2"/>
    </stack>
    </jgroups>

   <cache-container name="default" statistics="true">
      <transport cluster="${infinispan.cluster.name}" stack="${infinispan.cluster.stack:tcp}"/>
   </cache-container>

   <server xmlns="urn:infinispan:server:10.0">
      <interfaces>
         <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${infinispan.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
         </interface>
      </interfaces>

      <socket-bindings default-interface="public" port-offset="${infinispan.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
         <socket-binding name="default" port="${infinispan.bind.port:11222}"/>
         <socket-binding name="memcached" port="11221"/>
      </socket-bindings>

      <security>
         <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="default">
               <!-- Uncomment to enable TLS on the realm -->
               <!-- server-identities>
                  <ssl>
                     <keystore path="application.keystore" relative-to="infinispan.server.config.path"
                               keystore-password="password" alias="server" key-password="password"
                               generate-self-signed-certificate-host="localhost"/>
                  </ssl>
               </server-identities-->
               <properties-realm groups-attribute="Roles">
                  <user-properties path="users.properties" relative-to="infinispan.server.config.path"/>
                  <group-properties path="groups.properties" relative-to="infinispan.server.config.path" />
               </properties-realm>
            </security-realm>
         </security-realms>
      </security>

      <endpoints socket-binding="default" security-realm="default">
         <hotrod-connector name="hotrod"/>
         <rest-connector name="rest"/>
         <!-- Uncomment to enable the memcached connector -->
         <!-- memcached-connector socket-binding="memcached" / -->
      </endpoints>
   </server>
</infinispan>
```

'''

Infinispan Log Out:

```
2019-11-22 06:10:35,347 INFO  [BOOT] (main) JVM OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Oracle Corporation 25.232-b09
2019-11-22 06:10:35,360 INFO  [BOOT] (main) JVM arguments = -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=32M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=64m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dvisualvm.display.name=infinispan-server -Dinfinispan.server.home.path=/apps/infinispan/keycloak/infinispan-server-10.0.0.Final
2019-11-22 06:10:35,360 INFO  [BOOT] (main) PID = 76816
2019-11-22 06:10:35,394 INFO  [org.infinispan.SERVER] (main) ISPN080000: Infinispan Server starting
2019-11-22 06:10:35,395 INFO  [org.infinispan.SERVER] (main) ISPN080017: Server configuration: /apps/infinispan/keycloak/infinispan-server-10.0.0.Final/nodes/infinispan-keycloak1uat-ap-19430-01/conf/infinispan.xml
2019-11-22 06:10:35,768 FATAL [org.infinispan.SERVER] (main) ISPN080028: Infinispan Server failed to start: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[13,44]
Message: Unexpected element '{urn:infinispan:config:10.0}property' encountered
        at org.infinispan.server.Server.parseConfiguration(Server.java:243)
        at org.infinispan.server.Server.<init>(Server.java:168)
        at org.infinispan.server.Bootstrap.runInternal(Bootstrap.java:122)
        at org.infinispan.server.tool.Main.run(Main.java:98)
        at org.infinispan.server.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:41)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.infinispan.server.loader.Loader.main(Loader.java:52)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[13,44]
Message: Unexpected element '{urn:infinispan:config:10.0}property' encountered
        at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParseUtils.unexpectedElement(ParseUtils.java:37)
        at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParseUtils.requireNoContent(ParseUtils.java:147)
        at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.Parser.parseJGroupsStack(Parser.java:528)
        at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.Parser.parseJGroups(Parser.java:475)
        at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.Parser.readElement(Parser.java:129)
        at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parseElement(ParserRegistry.java:224)
        at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parse(ParserRegistry.java:194)
        at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parse(ParserRegistry.java:180)
        at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parse(ParserRegistry.java:169)
        at org.infinispan.server.Server.parseConfiguration(Server.java:225)
        ... 9 more

2019-11-22 06:10:35,771 INFO  [org.infinispan.SERVER] (Thread-1) ISPN080002: Infinispan Server stopping
2019-11-22 06:10:35,771 INFO  [org.infinispan.SERVER] (Thread-1) ISPN080003: Infinispan Server stopped
```

Updated:

```
<jgroups>
    <!-- Add JGroups stacks for Infinispan clustering. -->
    <stack name="uat">
      <TCP bind_port="7800" />
      <TCPPING timeout="3000"
           initial_hosts="${jgroups.tcpping.initial_hosts:1.1.1.1[7800],2.2.2.2[7800]}"
           port_range="1"
           num_initial_members="2"/>
      <MERGE3 />
      <FD_SOCK />
      <FD_ALL timeout="3000" interval="1000" timeout_check_interval="1000" />
      <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1000" />
      <pbcast.NAKACK2 use_mcast_xmit="false" xmit_interval="100" xmit_table_num_rows="50"
                      xmit_table_msgs_per_row="1024" xmit_table_max_compaction_time="30000" />
      <UNICAST3 xmit_interval="100" xmit_table_num_rows="50" xmit_table_msgs_per_row="1024"
                xmit_table_max_compaction_time="30000" />
      <pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="200" desired_avg_gossip="2000" max_bytes="1M" />
      <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="false" join_timeout="${jgroups.join_timeout:2000}" />
      <UFC_NB max_credits="3m" min_threshold="0.40" />
      <MFC_NB max_credits="3m" min_threshold="0.40" />
      <FRAG2 />
    </stack>
   </jgroups>
```

Using TCPPING:

```
2019-11-25 13:13:29,749 INFO  [BOOT] (main) JVM OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Oracle Corporation 25.232-b09
2019-11-25 13:13:29,762 INFO  [BOOT] (main) JVM arguments = -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=32M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=64m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dvisualvm.display.name=infinispan-server -Dinfinispan.server.home.path=/apps/infinispan/keycloak/infinispan-server-10.0.0.Final
2019-11-25 13:13:29,763 INFO  [BOOT] (main) PID = 71808
2019-11-25 13:13:29,798 INFO  [org.infinispan.SERVER] (main) ISPN080000: Infinispan Server starting
2019-11-25 13:13:29,799 INFO  [org.infinispan.SERVER] (main) ISPN080017: Server configuration: /apps/infinispan/keycloak/infinispan-server-10.0.0.Final/nodes/infinispan-keycloak1uat-ap-19430-02/conf/infinispan.xml
2019-11-25 13:13:30,345 INFO  [org.infinispan.SERVER] (main) ISPN080027: Loaded extension 'query-dsl-filter-converter-factory'
2019-11-25 13:13:30,345 INFO  [org.infinispan.SERVER] (main) ISPN080027: Loaded extension 'continuous-query-filter-converter-factory'
2019-11-25 13:13:30,347 INFO  [org.infinispan.SERVER] (main) ISPN080027: Loaded extension 'jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory'
2019-11-25 13:13:31,175 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (main) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chupacabra' 10.0.0.Final
2019-11-25 13:13:31,177 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (main) ISPN000389: Loaded global state, version=10.0.0.Final timestamp=2019-11-25T19:13:08.329Z
2019-11-25 13:13:31,333 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (main) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel infinispan-keycloak-cluster
2019-11-25 13:13:33,500 INFO  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (main) uat-ap-19430-02-63141: no members discovered after 2002 ms: creating cluster as first member
2019-11-25 13:13:33,510 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (main) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel infinispan-keycloak-cluster: [uat-ap-19430-02-63141|0] (1) [uat-ap-19430-02-63141]
2019-11-25 13:13:33,560 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (main) ISPN000079: Channel infinispan-keycloak-cluster local address is uat-ap-19430-02-63141, physical addresses are [1.1.1.1:7800]
2019-11-25 13:13:33,887 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (main) ISPN000104: Using EmbeddedTransactionManager
2019-11-25 13:13:34,063 INFO  [org.infinispan.SERVER] (main) ISPN080018: Protocol REST (internal)
2019-11-25 13:13:34,091 INFO  [org.infinispan.SERVER] (ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1) ISPN080018: Protocol HotRod (internal)
2019-11-25 13:13:34,219 INFO  [org.infinispan.SERVER] (main) ISPN080004: Protocol SINGLE_PORT listening on 1.1.1.1:11222
2019-11-25 13:13:34,219 INFO  [org.infinispan.SERVER] (main) ISPN080001: Infinispan Server 10.0.0.Final started in 4418ms
```

Thanks
Eric

Comment: can you share the full configuration? What error are you having?

Comment: I have added, thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should be using the JGroups schema: see https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#jgroups_inline-configuring

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get both Infinispan jvm's to start by using your suggestion, I did switch out MPING to TCPPING. Although now starting I'm not seeing any clustering messages in the logs. All ports are open between the two app servers.

Comment: Working now, needed to add --cluster-stack=uat to my start script. Thanks Again.